# I am facing some difficulties while calling .phtml file in list.phtml of magento

Tags: magento-1.9, product-list

This is the module that i am using in my project.
http://inchoo.net/magento/how-to-add-custom-product-relations-in-magento/

xml file path: app/design/frontend/theme/default/layout/inchoo_customlinkedproducts.xml:

```
<layout>
    <default>
        <catalog_product_view translate="label">
            <reference name="right">
                <block type="inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom" name="catalog.product.custom" before="-" template="inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml"/>
            </reference>
        </catalog_product_view>
    </default>
</layout>
```

Xml file of the module etc/config.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
        <modules>
            <Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts>
                <version>0.0.1</version>
            </Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts>
        </modules>
        <global>
            <blocks>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                    <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block</class>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
            </blocks>
            <helpers>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                    <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Helper</class>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
            </helpers>
            <models>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                    <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model</class>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                <catalog>
                    <rewrite>
                        <product>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product</product>
                        <product_link>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Catalog_Product_Link</product_link>
                    </rewrite>
                </catalog>
            </models>
            <resources>
                <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_setup>
                    <setup>
                        <module>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts</module>
                        <class>Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
                    </setup>
                </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_setup>
            </resources>
        </global>
        <admin>
            <routers>
                <adminhtml>
                    <args>
                        <modules>
                            <inchoo_customlinkedproducts before="Mage_Adminhtml">Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Adminhtml</inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                        </modules>
                    </args>
                </adminhtml>
            </routers>
        </admin>
        <frontend>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                        <file>inchoo_customlinkedproducts.xml</file>
                    </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                </updates>
            </layout>
        </frontend>
        <adminhtml>
            <layout>
                <updates>
                    <inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                        <file>inchoo_customlinkedproducts.xml</file>
                    </inchoo_customlinkedproducts>
                </updates>
            </layout>
            <events>
                <catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    <observers>
                        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                            <class>inchoo_customlinkedproducts/observer</class>
                            <method>catalogProductPrepareSave</method>
                        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_product_prepare_save>
                <catalog_model_product_duplicate>
                    <observers>
                        <inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                            <class>inchoo_customlinkedproducts/observer</class>
                            <method>catalogModelProductDuplicate</method>
                        </inchoo_customlinkedproducts_catalog_product_prepare_save>
                    </observers>
                </catalog_model_product_duplicate>
            </events>
        </adminhtml>
    </config>
```

code of **Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Custom**

```
class Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Custom extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_mapRenderer = 'msrp_noform';

    protected $_itemCollection;

    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = Mage::registry('product');

        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getCustomProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
}
```

I have called in **view.phtml** file:

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom')->setTemplate('inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Can any one tell me how to call in **list.phtml**

Comment: recheck your block name `inchoo_customlinkedproducts` in blocks tag

Comment: Have you created `config.xml` for this module if yes then please share and if no then create one and share

Comment: @murtuza i have created xml file for that check the above code for that

Comment: @prashanth its your layout file I am talking about `etc/config.xml` file

Comment: @murtuza check the updated question

Comment: provide `Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Custom` class code

Comment: @murtuza check updated question

Comment: Does your code work on **view.phtml**? If not, then check if your block `inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom` have permission set to Allowed in `System > Permissions > Block` section.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The code won't work on list page because,

1. In the reference link, the module is to display custom products which are assigned to a product. It gets data from a singl product and add it to the related template.
2. Your block **Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_Custom** checks for `$product = Mage::registry('product');` which will not be available on list page. So, the code to get collection will not work.

   ```
   $this->_itemCollection = $product->getCustomProductCollection()
   ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
   ->setPositionOrder()
   ->addStoreFilter();
   ```

If you add

```
<?php 
    echo $this->getLayout()
       ->createBlock('inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom')
       ->setTemplate('inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml')
       ->toHtml(); 
?>
```

on your list page and enable template path hints, you will see the block but it will be empty.
Now to use the same functionality on list page, first you need to get all products in category, get all custom link products for each of them and then set the collection to your template file.

**EDIT**
To display Custom Linked products on List page,
Create a new block in **app\code\community\Inchoo\CustomLinkedProducts\Block\Catalog\Product\List\CustomList.php** file

```
class Inchoo_CustomLinkedProducts_Block_Catalog_Product_List_CustomList extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_Abstract
{
    protected $_mapRenderer = 'msrp_noform';

    protected $_itemCollection;

    protected function _prepareData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        $this->_itemCollection = $product->getCustomProductCollection()
            ->addAttributeToSelect('required_options')
            ->setPositionOrder()
            ->addStoreFilter()
        ;

        if (Mage::helper('catalog')->isModuleEnabled('Mage_Checkout')) {
            Mage::getResourceSingleton('checkout/cart')->addExcludeProductFilter($this->_itemCollection,
                Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuoteId()
            );
            $this->_addProductAttributesAndPrices($this->_itemCollection);
        }

        Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_visibility')->addVisibleInCatalogFilterToCollection($this->_itemCollection);

        $this->_itemCollection->load();

        foreach ($this->_itemCollection as $product) {
            $product->setDoNotUseCategoryId(true);
        }

        return $this;
    }

    protected function _beforeToHtml()
    {
        $this->_prepareData();
        return parent::_beforeToHtml();
    }

    public function getItems()
    {
        return $this->_itemCollection;
    }
}
```

Now create a phtml file in **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\inchoo\catalog\product\list\custom_list.phtml**

```
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
<div class="block block-custom">
    <div class="block-title">
        <strong><span><?php echo $this->__('Custom Linked Products') ?></span></strong>
    </div>
    <div class="block-content">
        <ol class="mini-products-list" id="block-custom">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item):
              $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($_item->getId()); ?>
            <li class="item">
                <div class="product">
                    <p class="product-name"><a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a></p>
                </div>
                <span><?php echo $_product->getJuiceCommonName(); ?></span>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>

    </div>
</div>
<?php endif ?>
```

Now, you can call this to your list page with below code in your **list.phtml**,

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_customList')->setProduct($_product)->setTemplate('inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom_list.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: can you pls explain me how to do it

Comment: Are you sure you want to do it this way? It will get all customlink products for each product for a category and will display it on page, which will considerably downgrade the performance of the page. Just let me know if you are sure about this.

Comment: i want to display only customlinked product name in listing page of magento

Comment: @prashanth, Please check my edits. I have tested it and it is working. It will show you names of all linked products.

Comment: Code is working fine.but one problem is that for everyproduct its showing same customlinked product name.it should show productwise customlinked product name

Comment: @prashanth, Updated code to make it work for each product. Please check.

Comment: updated code doesn't working

Comment: Did you update block file as per new code? Also I have updated code which you need to add to your list.phtml. please confirm as I have tested the code and it's working

Comment: can i know how to fetch attribute value for customedlinkedProducts

Comment: You can use `$_item->getProduct()->getYOUR_ATTRIBUTE_NAME()`

Comment: i am getting this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function getjuice_common_name() on null in my attribute code :juice_common_name

Comment: check updated **app\design\frontend\base\default\template\inchoo\catalog\product\list\custom_list.phtml** file code

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getId() on null

Comment: Ohh.. sorry, please use `$_item->getId()`

Answer (score 2):

put below code in your local.xml

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">  <!-- Name of list Block -->
        <block type="inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom" name="catalog.product.view.custom" as="view_custom" template="inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

call below line in your list.phtml file

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('view_custom') ?>
```

or just add this line in list.phtml

```
<?php echo $this->getLayout()->createBlock('inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom')->setTemplate('inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml')->toHtml(); ?>
```

Comment: i want to call in list.phtml not in view.phtml

Comment: @prashanth find updated answer

Comment: still not calling

Comment: make sure name in the reference is same as list block name.. it may be different if you are using theme @prashanth

Comment: check the updated question

Answer (score 1):

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="product_list">  <!-- Name of list Block -->
        <block type="inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom" name="catalog.product.view.custom" as="view_custom" template="inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

**You can replace with this**

```
<catalog_category_default>
    <reference name="content">  <!-- Name of list Block -->
        <block type="inchoo_customlinkedproducts/catalog_product_list_custom" name="catalog.product.view.custom" as="view_custom" template="inchoo/catalog/product/list/custom.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```